# Least Square approximation

Tags: optimization, definite-integrals, solution-verification, absolute-value, upper-lower-bounds

Solve the following minimization problems and determine whether there is a unique value of $\alpha$ that gives the minimum.

In each case, $\alpha$ is allowed to range over all real numbers. We are approximating the function $f(x) = x$ with polynomials of the form $\alpha x^2$.

(a) $min_{\alpha} \int_{-1}^{1}(x-\alpha x^2)^2 dx$

(b)$min_{\alpha} \int_{-1}^{1}|x-\alpha x^2| dx$

(c)$min_{\alpha} max_{-1 \leq x \leq 1} |x-\alpha x^2| $

**My approach**

For part (a):

First I integrated and then took the minimum over $\alpha$ and ended with $\alpha =0$ as the minimum.

Part (b):

I defined the function $$|x-\alpha x^2|= \begin{cases}
x-\alpha x^2, x \geq \alpha x^2\\
-(x-\alpha x^2),x \lt \alpha x^2\\
\end{cases}$$

For integration, I took two cases for $\alpha \gt 0 \text{ and } \alpha \lt 0$.

For $\alpha \gt 0$ and $x \gt 0 \implies \text{ either }x-\alpha x^2 \geq 0 \text{ or } x-\alpha x^2 \lt 0 $. Greater than equal case is when $x \leq \frac{1}{\alpha}$ and less than when $x \gt \frac{1}{\alpha}$, also if $\alpha \gt 0$ and $x \lt 0 \implies x-\alpha x^2 \lt 0 $,

Therefore, the integral can be written as :$$\int_{-1}^{1}|x-\alpha x^2| dx = \int_{-1}^{0} -(x-\alpha x^2)dx +\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\alpha}} (x-\alpha x^2) dx + \int_{1/\alpha}^{1} -(x-\alpha x^2) dx $$

Solving the integration I obtained the function of $f(\alpha)= \frac{2\alpha}{3} + \frac{1}{3 \alpha^2}$, solving for the minimum gives me $\alpha =1$.

Is my approach right? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: With my approach, I am getting $\alpha =1$ for part (b).

Comment: There is the additional caveat that you assume $\alpha\ge1$ when you split the integral that way in part b. Consider what happens if $0\le\alpha\le1$ to the bounds of the integrals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the provided approach, however I think that it is easier to use symmetry for these problems:

\begin{align}A&=\int_{-1}^1(x-\alpha x^2)^2~\mathrm dx\\&=\int_0^1(x-\alpha x^2)^2+(x+\alpha x^2)^2~\mathrm dx\\&=2\int_0^1x^2+\alpha^2x^4~\mathrm dx\end{align}

at which point it is already obvious this is minimized at $\alpha=0$ for part a.

---

Similarly for part b:

\begin{align}B&=\int_{-1}^1|x-\alpha x^2|~\mathrm dx\\&=\int_0^1|x-\alpha x^2|+|x+\alpha x^2|~\mathrm dx\\&=2\int_0^1\max(|x|,|\alpha x^2|)~\mathrm dx\end{align}

Again, without actually working out the integral, we can see this is minimized at $\alpha=0$. I leave it to the reader to see that $\alpha=0$ is not the unique answer here.

---

For part c, you want to find the local extrema of $x-\alpha x^2$. This can be done by finding where it has vanishing derivative and additionally checking the endpoints $x=\pm1$.

Comment: I have edited part (c).

Comment: can you explain how you wrote the integral in part (b)?

Comment: I added the portion for $x\ge0$ and $x\le0$ and then used the identity $2\max(|a|,|b|)=|a+b|+|a-b|$.

Comment: how you wrote the second step of part b?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what's vague, given my last comment. Are you asking about this?: $$\int_0^1|x-\alpha x^2|+|x+\alpha x^2|~\mathrm dx=2\int_0^1\max(|x|,|\alpha x^2|)~\mathrm dx$$If so, this makes use of the relationship between $\max$ and absolute values pointed out in the previous comment.

Comment: $\begin{align}B&=\int_{-1}^1|x-\alpha x^2|~\mathrm dx\\&=\int_0^1|x-\alpha x^2|+|x+\alpha x^2|~\mathrm dx \end{align}$ going from step 1 to 2.

Comment: We use $\int_{-1}^1f(x)~\mathrm dx=\int_0^1f(x)+f(-x)~\mathrm dx$.

Comment: I don't understand how to get a minimum value at $\alpha =0$, part(b).

Comment: I think for part(b) the value should be 1. Since, when $0\leq x \leq 1, max(|x|,|\alpha x^2|)=x$.

Comment: Trivially when $\alpha=0$, $\max(|x|,0)=|x|$. As I state, there are multiple $\alpha$'s for that part. That includes $\alpha=1$.